# Can varip be used for current bar?

Tags: pine-script

[![Thursday a.m. Screen shot][1]][1]Is it possible to use varip so that the code below will print on the current, real time bar that is still forming instead of just the historical bars?

In looking at the recent varip articles I tried the following example and it doesn't print the plotcandle on the current bar either:

```
varip int updateNo = na
if barstate.isnew
    updateNo := 1
else
    updateNo := updateNo + 1

Up      =   close >= open and updateNo == 1
Down    =   close < open and updateNo == 1

//  -------------------------
//@version=4

study(title="Candle overlay")

Up      = close >= open
Down    = close < open

plotcandle(
     Up ? open : na,
     Up ? high : na,
     Up ? low : na,
     Up ? close : na, color = color.lime, bordercolor = color.gray, 
wickcolor = color.gray
     )
     
plotcandle(
     Down ? open : na,
     Down ? high : na,
     Down ? low : na,
     Down ? close : na, color = color.red, bordercolor = color.gray, 
wickcolor = color.gray
     )
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2q2Q.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include detection of the realtime bar in your conditions, you can restrict the plotting the way you want:

```
Up      = barstate.isrealtime and close >= open
Down    = barstate.isrealtime and close < open
```

If you don't want your indie to lead a trail of candles on elapsed realtime bars, you can use:

```
Up      = barstate.isrealtime and not barstate.isconfirmed and close >= open
Down    = barstate.isrealtime and not barstate.isconfirmed and close < open
```

which makes the condition `false` on the last update (the close) of realtime bars.

So you don't need `varip` in there. `varip` is useful when you need to preserve states between realtime bar updates, just as `var` preserves values across bars because it only initializes variables on the dataset's first bar. See [this PineCoders publication](https://www.tradingview.com/script/ppQxBISk-Using-varip-variables-PineCoders/)  for more info on `varip`.

[EDIT 2021.05.06 10:24 — LucF]

This shows both example in play:
[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts and quick response!!  Unfortunately neither example worked on the bar that is currently printing.  The first idea you shared worked on historical bars that had been printed in real time, but it didn't work on the bar that is currently printing.  
The 2nd example didn't work on either.  I asked TV support if varip would work on the real time bar and they said yes. I'm just not sure how to code varip.  I'm hoping to have the candle overlay work on All bars since Range bars are unfortunately Not offered in candles....

Comment: If you want to restrict the plotting of your candle to realtime bars (which is how we understood your question) the code we supplied works and you don't need `varip` to achieve it, as we mentioned. We added a screenshot showing the display you get for each example. If we misunderstood your question, our apologies. If that's the case, perhaps you can rephrase it?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts! Your idea works great on time-based charts, but not on Range Bars. I wish TV offered Range bars as candles instead of OHLC.